# How to continue executing the next other commands after using "kill" in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, kill

I want to merge two different script files into one script file which could do what the two different files do. And the script files is:

script file A:

```
pid=`ps -ef | grep temp_tool | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
kill -9 ${pid}
```

script file B:

```
nohup ./temp_tool &
```

the merged script file:

```
pid=`ps -ef | grep temp_tool | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
kill -9 ${pid}
nohup ./temp_tool &
```

The whole merged script file would stop after executing `kill` command, and I have to modify it to be:

```
pid=`ps -ef | grep temp_tool | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
out=`kill -9 ${pid}`
nohup ./temp_tool &
```

and it works well now, but I don't know why? Is there any difference?

Comment: What 'ps -ef | grep temp_tool' outputs, can you paste it here.

Comment: what is the name of your script? Something like `check_temp_tool` or similar?

Comment: the output of `ps -ef | grep temp_tool` is: root     15920 15876  0 10:57 pts/17   00:00:00 ./temp_tool

Comment: the name of my script is "monitor.sh".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say `$pid` also contains the pid of your script. You can filter it out:

```
script_pid=$$
pid=$(ps -ef | grep temp_tool | grep -Ev "grep|$script_pid" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Though if you want the pids of the command `temp_tool` I would suggest this:

```
ps -C temp_tool -o pid
```

Instead of the `ps -ef | grep ...`